# VSCode Remote tunnel and extensions / import’s problem

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-server

I just got VSCode tunnels ‘working’ by enabling it in the GUI, and copy and pasting the link into safari on my iPad

Problem is , it doesn’t use any of the imports. Just says ‘module requests doesnt exist’

I thought tunnels was just basically a fancy backend Remote Desktop that takes what I type in, and runs it on my server machine, why would none of my imports or libraries work?